# How can I run an Apache Spark batch job on top of a Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I need to query a log compacted topic (just the current snapshot via an export-to-ftp batch job) to de duplicate & reorder the records.
How can I load a Kafka topic (Avro) as RDD?